# SQL: Extracting row segment pertaining to maximum value of a column for each unique entity in some other column

Tags: sql

I have ‘Input Table’ as shown in attached snapshot.
Using SQL, I am intending to build an ‘Output Table’ where:
‘MaxDays’: should show the maximum value of ‘Days’ for a given ‘ID’
‘Type_MaxDays’: is the corresponding value of ‘Type’ pertaining to the maximum ‘Days’ identified for ‘MaxDays’
‘TotalUniqueType’: Counts all the unique ‘Type’ for any given ID

For example, for ID=878, Days=90 is the maximum of (63, 90, 33, 48) and it corresponds to Type=A. Hence, in output table, Max_Days= 90 and Type_MaxDays= A. Since ID=878 has total 4 unique 'Type' (ie.. A, B, C, D) so TotalUniqueType=4.

Finding the ‘TotalUniqueType’ seems straightforward, however coming from a python/pandas background, I am not able to figure out how to retrieve ‘MaxDays’ and ‘Type_MaxDays’ using SQL. Please advise.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to join to a subquery which finds, for each `ID`, the maximum number of days along with the distinct type count.  Then, also select the type of the row having the maximum number of days.

```
SELECT
    t1.ID,
    t1.Days AS MaxDays,
    t1.Type AS Type_MaxDays,
    t2.TypeCnt AS TotalUniqueType
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ID, MAX(Days) AS MaxDays, COUNT(DISTINCT Type) AS TypeCnt
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY ID
) t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID AND t1.Days = t2.MaxDays;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend window functions and aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(days) as maxdays,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then type end) as type_at_maxdays,
       count(distinct type)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by days desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by id;
```